# Pass javascript variables from a html page to another using local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to make a web app which counts the amount of homework one hasn't done. Basically, there is a "main" page with a table containing the pupils in which the teacher can press a button if one has made the homework or  another one if one hasn't. I also created a page for every student to see his own "counters". Is there any way to transfer the counter of each pupil from the "main" page to his own page in order to see them privately? Is there any way to do this by using local storage?

Comment: I think the best approach its to save it to a database, if you dont have a backend service I really recommend to take a look on firebase.com

Comment: isn't there any way to do this without a backend service? i develop at a small scale and i'm using google drive as a host and a free dot.tk domain

Comment: `Is there any way to do this by using local storage?` - No. Anything in localStorage is only on that person's computer.

Comment: really? I thought they are saved over the internet and that's why when you declare something with local storage it doesn't lose after refreshing the page

Comment: Local storage doesn't disappear because it doesn't have an expiration date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use a database, the easiest is to write the data of each student in a file.

Comment: what do you mean by file? the counters change constantly and how can i apply the changes to them in file? i'm a newbie so excuse if this is an idiot question

Comment: It's difficult to help you without your html file. Can you post a part of your code ?